How to Retrieve Last Balance for Filtered Months in Matrix Visual?
I have some data from the "Reconciliation" table, which includes Date ID, Account ID, and Balance:



Date ID
Account ID
Balance




20240101
A
100


20240201
A
200


20240301
B
300



Additionally, I have a date table connected to the Date ID. I'm trying to create a function that returns the last balance for the last date relative to the filtered month.
What I Want:
Ultimately, I aim to create a matrix visual with Dates[YYYYMM] as columns, Reconciliation[Account ID] as rows, and a new measure "Last Balance" as values:



-------
202401
202402
202403




A
100
200
200


B


300



What I've Tried:
I attempted this formula, but it leaves the last balance for account A blank:
LastBalance = CALCULATE(SUM(Reconciliation[Balance]),
Reconciliation[Date ID] = MAX(Reconciliation[Date ID]))
Resulting in:



-------
202401
202402
202403




A
100
200
*


B


300



The Problem:
This approach leaves the last month for the A account empty. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

This finally solved it for me :)
LastBalance = 
VAR MaxDate = 

CALCULATE(MAX(Reconciliation[Date ID]),
    ALL(Dates),
    Dates[Date ID] <= MAX(Dates[Date ID]))

RETURN 
    CALCULATE(SUM(Reconciliation[Balance]),
    ALL(Dates),
    Reconciliation[Date ID] = MaxDate)

